# Django 1.6 cannot start shell, simple_translation.utils not found

Tags: python, django

I recently started a new Django project from scratch in Django 1.6. When I try to open the shell using manage.py or when I try to run server I am getting this error

```
ImportError: No module named simple_translation.utils
```

The same thing happens when I try to run south migrations.

I searched on the net but I am unable to find anything that says I need to install this module after I create a new Django 1.6 project.

I am installing these packages and I don't see any issues when I do a pip install with these -

- Django
- South
- django-hero-slider
- django-calendarium
- django-people
  psycopg2

Edit: When I manually install this module, I am able to get the project working again. So the question I guess is what changes from 1.5 made this extra step necessary?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [third-party module](http://simple-translation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and is not part of django.

django doesn't need this module, chances are something you have installed needs this module; and if you look at the full traceback, it will have clues as to where it is being imported.

You should look at the requirements for your additional packages.

Comment: looking through my pip freeze output, looks like a lot of other stuff like Jinja etc were installed, and from one of the packages django-hero-slider I see a reference to django-cms which isn't installed. Probably something on that which is broken and resulted in this error. Will try to dig into the dependency tree and see if I can spot exactly where this is broken and add it in.